# decompose of symmetric product of the so(8)-adjoint representation

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Consider the adjoint representation $\mathbf{28}$ of $\mathfrak{so}(8)$. The generators can be written as $J_{ij} = - J_{ji}$ with the standard commutation relations, where $i,j = 1, ..., 8$.

The tensor product of $\mathbf{28}$ with itself is
$$
\mathbf{28} \otimes \mathbf{28} = \underbrace{\mathbf{1} \oplus \mathbf{35}_v \oplus \mathbf{35}_s \oplus \mathbf{35}_c \oplus \mathbf{300}}_{\text{symm}^2 \mathbf{28}} \oplus \mathbf{28} \oplus \mathbf{350} \ .
$$

I wonder how to explicitly decompose the $J_{ij}J_{k\ell}$ into these different pieces? Naively I think
$$
\mathbf{1} \sim \sum_{ij}J_{ij}J_{ij}, \quad
\mathbf{35}_v \sim \sum_k J_{ik}J_{jk} - \frac{1}{8} \delta_{ij} \sum_{pq}J_{pq}J_{pq}, \quad
\mathbf{28} \sim J_{ij} \text{ by commutation relations}
$$
But I wasn't able to work out the rest.

Comment: I think this may be a little more complicated than you'd like. For a start a natural basis of the symmetric parts all put together would be of the form $J_{ij}J_{kl} +J_{kl}J_{ij}$. I'm not sure your basis for one of the 35-diml parts would work. I'm also not sure what you mean by $J_{ij}$ being a basis for the 28 dimensional part. That part should be in the alternating part so in the span of $J_{ij}J_{kl} - J_{kl}J_{ij}$. Also a small typo the three 35-diml reps should all be different (trace-free symmetric squares of the 3 different 8-diml reps)

Comment: The 1-dimensional part should be the span of the Killing form and that looks correct. Off the top of my head the decomposition of the alternating parts should be directly related to the Killing form as well but I cannot remember the details of this. Note whenever there is a trivial irrep in $S^2V$ there is a copy of the adjoint rep in $\bigwedge^2V$ and vice versa.